# Database Approach - Redundant data

Tags: mysql, duplicates, redundancy

I have 3 tables:

```
products (id, name, price, etc)
orders (id, date, payment_method, etc)
shipments (id, order_id, product_id, address, etc)
```

My question is: It is correct to keep in shipments table product_id? I keep it here to find information about a shipped product without using orders table.

Comment: Do orders not contain products?  It would seem to me that an order has 1->n products and 1->n shipments.  Is this not the case?

Comment: what will you do if you have two products on the same order?

Comment: why do it this way ? You only need to write the appropriate join to get data from the correctly normalised version of your schema

Comment: A order has just one product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
products (product_id, name, price, etc)
orders (order_id, date, payment_method, etc)
orderitem (orderitem_id, order_id, product_id, ...)
shipment (shipment_id, order_id, ... )
```

shipment is kind of redundant - I'd add the address etc into orders...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but be careful - if the information in table orders could change, it would be a problem - i.e. if the appropriate record in table orders changes the product_id, the database would be inconsistent.

I do use redundant columns e.g. in static dictionaries.

Also check for the NORMAL FORMS (NF) of database desing, I'm not sure if this redundancy doesn't violate some normal form. But it is up to you if you decide to keep some NF or not.

Comment: The info in the product table has the current price, while the info in the order/shipment table has the price as of when the order was shipped. So this would not really violate database design principles -- one is the template, and one is an instance of that template.

Comment: @MJB Just now something came up to my mind. Users can see a history for products ordered. What will happen if admin edit info about a product (name, description)? Now to avoid this problem products are locked if are ordered.

Comment: @morandi3: Some systems also support the notion of different "revisions" of an item (like model year, or region-specific variations).

Answer (score 1):

Following the principles of truth and beauty, you should not store redundant data - it's a great opportunity for bugs to occur, it's ugly, it causes confusion in the minds of future developers.

You're allowed to break the principles of truth and beauty, but only if you run into a problem you cannot solve in any other way. For instance, if you find your queries are just too slow by joining to the orders table, denormalizing the data (which is the technical name for what you're doing) is okay - if you document it and make sure all developers understand.

Just avoiding an extra join in a query doesn't seem like a good enough reason....